# FileUpload thows exception - help

Tags: java, file-io, file-upload

I am writing a simple FileUpload code but as I run it I alway get a long exception ...

...

> root cause
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream

...

I watched the FileUpload lib jars and they all are really **missing** DeferredFileOutputStream. So my question is where to find this DeferredFileOutputStream? What additional lib should I add to my project to have the class?

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to the classpath. Commons File Upload is dependent on it.

Answer (score 2):

DeferredFileOutputStream is part of the [Apache Commons IO project](http://commons.apache.org/io/). You will need to add the commons-io jar file to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Struts is using the “commons-io.jar” library for the file upload process. You have to include this library into your project dependency library folder.
[Link with more information](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-orgapachecommonsiooutputdeferredfileoutputstream/)

Comment: When did he say that he is using Struts?

Comment: Thank you :)

I was wondering why the current FileUpload version does not support the newest commons-io lib ?